# Resources$NotFoundException when using vector images on API22 but not on API24

Tags: java, android, svg, vector

I'm facing an issue with the use of `vector` in Android.

I'm using vectors (from SVG imported in android studio) to display an image as a background of my `Textview` using `android:background="@drawable/ic_blue2"`

While everything worked well when testing on a phone with API24, the application crashes on startup on phones with API22 with InflateException and Resources$NotFoundException.

I tried answers to previous posts such as adding to Gradle  `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` but it didn't work.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and Gradle 3.0.1. And please note that my activity extends "Activity" and not AppCompatActivity (don't know if it's important here).

Here is the code of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundWhite"
    tools:context="jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_gray7"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAppname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_blue7"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBackgroundWhite"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSolo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_blue2"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/solo"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBackgroundWhite"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonMulti"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_blue2"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/multi"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBackgroundWhite"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewVersion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Version"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBackgroundWhite" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

An example of the xml I try to use as background (file is too big)https://pastebin.com/DRR5eRm0

And the error on API22

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: jdev.com.handtwist, PID: 4666
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jdev.com.handtwist/jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3160)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:450)
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400)
                      at jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:40)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:450) 
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400) 
                      at jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:40) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_gray7.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0603a5
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4061)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3779)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
                      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4001)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:513)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:191)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:450) 
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400) 
                      at jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:40) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v22/$ic_gray7__0.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f060118
                      at android.content.res.Resources.twLoadColorStateList(Resources.java:4179)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:4117)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:397)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1439)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1418)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateInternal(VectorDrawable.java:544)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:460)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1192)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1086)
                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDraw
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Edit : when trying to use the Ben's approach error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: jdev.com.handtwist, PID: 16157
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jdev.com.handtwist/jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_testb.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0603ce
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3160)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_testb.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0603ce
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4061)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1991)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1973)
                      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:409)
                      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
                      at jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:63)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-anydpi-v22/$ic_testb__0.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f060295
                      at android.content.res.Resources.twLoadColorStateList(Resources.java:4179)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:4117)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:397)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1439)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1418)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateInternal(VectorDrawable.java:544)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:460)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1192)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1086)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4045)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929) 
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1991) 
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1973) 
                      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:409) 
                      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351) 
                      at jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:63) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0: invalid drawable tag gradient
                      at android.content.res.ColorStateList.twCreateFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:176)
                      at android.content.res.ColorStateList.twCreateFromXml(ColorStateList.java:147)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.twLoadColorStateList(Resources.java:4175)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:4117) 
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:397) 
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1439) 
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1418) 
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateInternal(VectorDrawable.java:544) 
                      at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:460) 
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1192) 
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1086) 
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4045) 
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3929) 
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1991) 
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1973) 
                      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:409) 
                      at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351) 
                      at jdev.com.handtwist.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:63) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: It looks like is having some trouble loading res/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_gray7.xml. Do you have a version for an API above v22 (like v23)? Could you add the contents of this drawable?

Comment: I can't test (for the moment) on other API. I have added in the post the content of an xml file I try to use.

Answer (score 0):

Native support for vector drawables in XML just does not exist for older API levels. You can use them in `ImageView`s because of the special `app:srcCompat` attribute, but you can't use them for `android:background` etc.

However, you *can* use them in Java. Something like

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.buttonSolo);
Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_blue2);
b.setBackground(d);
```

should work on all API levels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code, however it does not work. I guess I will have to deal with this and either forget vector or support only API>=24 as it works with `android:background`.

Comment: I added in the first post the error log. Same kind of issue. However I don't understand why the app try to locate xml in `res/drawable-anydpi-v21` and then `res/drawable-anydpi-v22` while the xml are in res/drawable. I tried placing the xml in those folder and it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

From the (updated) link in pastebin to you asset, it looks like you're using new XML bundle format. Notice the `<aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">` nodes. See [this G+ post](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/A8KKxnJdg4r) from [Nick Butcher](https://twitter.com/crafty). Even if it's about animated vector drawables, it applies to your case as I'm sure the mechanism is the same.

The important bit to check is:

> This requires Build Tools 24+ (currently in RC) but the output is backward compatible.

So, could should check that your build tools are updated.

Comment: my bad ! I did upload to pastebin the svg and not the xml, I updated my post https://pastebin.com/DRR5eRm0   really sorry for this.

Comment: I'm using 27.0.1, so the lastest version

Comment: Then it can be a bug. I've found this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70940261 in Google issue tracker, that could be related. In the meantime I think next step should be opening the generated APK with Shift-Cmd-A -> Analyze APK... from Android Studio and try to find your drawable, and add it to your question.